# Cannot connect Raspberry pi to android using wifi direct

Tags: pi-3b+, android, wifi-direct

I am not able to connect to Raspberry pi 3 using Wifi direct from android phone, What I tried is

Step 1:
Changed the configuration in wpa_supplicant.conf and the contents are

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=IN
ap_scan=1
device_name=Raspberry_pi
device_type=1-0050F204-1
driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1

network={
    ssid="myNetwork"
    psk="<passPhrase>"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}

network={
    ssid="Raspberry"
    psk="<passPhrase>"
}
```

Step 2

Loaded configuration using

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/p2p.conf -B
```

and the result is

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ctrl_iface exists and seems to be in use - cannot override it
Delete '/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0' manually if it is not used anymore
Failed to initialize control interface 'DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev'.
You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was
left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need
to manually remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again.

nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
```

Step 3

Then started the wpa_cli

when running the command, `p2p_find 60` it shows my android device and the android device can detect the PI device when a connection is initiated from the android, it will ask for the password/pin and the generated pin is displayed in the wpa_cli console. And after the pin is entered android phone shows `invite send` and nothing happens thereafter. when a `status` is issued in the wpa_cli terminal, it shows disconnected. How can I make the two devices connect? What changes should I make to make this working? Ant help will be appreciated. Please ask if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little bit difficult to examine what exactly goes wrong with your setup. **wpa_supplicant** claims that there may be already running an instance on interface **wlan0**. It could be that **wpa_supplicant** is already started on boot up. Before starting wpa_supplicant you can `sudo killall wpa_supplicant` to ensure that there is no other service running.

Then you try to make a connection with pin code method initiated from the android device. I suggest to use push button control (pbc) initiated from the RasPi. It is a bit simpler and you have better control over the handshake. How to do it you can look at [Setting up Wifi direct (wifi p2p) and DHCP server](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/94251/79866).