# Can we control a RPI with an Android smartphone wirelessly and without Wi-Fi?

Tags: wifi, android, headless, wifi-direct

I got a RPI4 and I would like to use it outside, where there is not always an avaiable Wi-Fi connection . I would like to create a sort of an headless machine and control it with a smartphone, without having to reconfigure it everytime I use it.

1) What are the ways I could use to control it "wirelessely" ?

2) Should I try to turn it in a hotspot and connect to it via Wi-Fi with the smartphone ?

3) Or should I try to make it connect to the hotspot of the smartphone ?

4) Can I use Wi-Fi direct with a RPI4 ?

Comment: 1) bluetooth is an option. 2) yes, 3) yes, 4) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94171/setting-up-wifi-direct-wifi-p2p-and-dhcp-server

Comment: option 3 makes no sense for a headless machine

Comment: Number **2** is the most reliable option for you. Others may challenge you in different situations.

Comment: @JaromandaX, why don’t you write that as an answer?